# Tensorflow: How to insert an unknown tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, typeerror, tensor

I want to serialize the data for input of LSTM model, for exmaple,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_x=np.array([[1,2,1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4],[10,20,1,2,1,2],[30,40,3,4,3,4],[100,200,1,2,1,2],[300,400,3,4,3,4]])#shape:6-6
# x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,6])
x=input_x
x_copy=x.copy()
# x_copy=tf.identity(x)

batch_size=6
n_steps=2

count=0
for i in range(int(batch_size/n_steps)-1):#total insert
    for j in range(n_steps-1):
        for k in range(n_steps):
            x_copy=np.insert(x_copy,(i+1)*n_steps+count,x[i*n_steps+j+k+1],axis=0)
            count+=1
res=x_copy
print('input_x\n',input_x)
print('res\n',res)
```

The output is as follows:

```
input_x
 [[  1   2   1   2   1   2]
 [  3   4   3   4   3   4]
 [ 10  20   1   2   1   2]
 [ 30  40   3   4   3   4]
 [100 200   1   2   1   2]
 [300 400   3   4   3   4]]
res
 [[  1   2   1   2   1   2]
 [  3   4   3   4   3   4]
 [  3   4   3   4   3   4]
 [ 10  20   1   2   1   2]
 [ 10  20   1   2   1   2]
 [ 30  40   3   4   3   4]
 [ 30  40   3   4   3   4]
 [100 200   1   2   1   2]
 [100 200   1   2   1   2]
 [300 400   3   4   3   4]]
```

As I set the n_steps=2,so the data will repeat once except the first row and the last row.

However,now I want to operate with tensor instead of array.And the code is changed as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_x=np.array([[1,2,1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4],[10,20,1,2,1,2],[30,40,3,4,3,4],[100,200,1,2,1,2],[300,400,3,4,3,4]])#shape:6-6
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,6])
# x=input_x

# x_copy=x.copy()
x_copy=tf.identity(x)

batch_size=6
n_steps=2

count=0
for i in range(int(batch_size/n_steps)-1):#total insert
    for j in range(n_steps-1):
        for k in range(n_steps):
            x_copy=np.insert(x_copy,(i+1)*n_steps+count,x[i*n_steps+j+k+1],axis=0)
            count+=1
res=x_copy
# print('input_x\n',input_x)
# print('res\n',res)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    batch_x=input_x
    result=sess.run([res,],feed_dict={
        x:batch_x,
    })
    print('result\n',result)
```

Then I meet a error, which can be shown as follows:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument array(<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_3:0' shape=(6,) dtype=float32>,
      dtype=object) has invalid type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I think all the variables should be tensor,but I get the typeerror which shows that I feed an array type.

Anybody knows it? Hopefully for your help,thanks!

Comment: Your first code, even if it works, is inefficient.  `np.insert` creates a new array; it doesn't just modify the input.  It's not a good idea to use that in a loop, much less nested loops.  That could also be the tensorflow problem  You may start `x_copy` as a `tf`, but after one `insert` it will be a `ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think you're right. And now I don't have a good idea to implement it. Maybe I should use `tf.tile` instead of `np.insert`.

Comment: OK，Maybe I solve the problem by using `tf.slice()` and `tf.concat()`. First copy the tensor by `tf.slice()`, then concat them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# for i in range(int(batch_size-n_steps)+1):#total insert
    # for k in range(n_steps):
        # hidden1_copy_tmp=tf.slice(hidden1, [k+i, 0], [1, hidden1.shape[1]])
        # if hidden1_copy== None:
            # hidden1_copy=hidden1_copy_tmp
        # else:
            # hidden1_copy=tf.concat([hidden1_copy, hidden1_copy_tmp], 0)
```